# link_to with Namespaces in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I'm trying to get an admin interface working in Rails, but I'm having trouble using `link_to` with the nested routes. I'm trying to get a link to `/admin/cake_class/:id` but it's sending me to `admin/cake_class.:id` instead.

`config/routes.rb:`

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :cake_class
end
```

`/app/views/admin/cake_class/index.html.erb`

```
<h1>all classes</h1>

<% @classes.each do |c| %>

    <%= c.date %>
    <%= c.name %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', admin_cake_class_path(c) %>

<% end %>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :resources should be plural, :cake_classes, which could be tripping you up.

What does the output of rake routes show?